# AssertionError: [101, 1203, 1365, 1137, 8601, 117, 4835, 1104, 1141, 1292, 119, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] is not <class 'list'>

Tags: python, assert

Even though the preprocess function is returning the list, assertion error is being raised everytime

```
pre = n.preprocess("New York or Mumbai, choose of one these.")
j = []
for i in range(4):
   ##To check the data type
   print("preprocess", type(pre[i]))
   self.assertIs(pre[i], list)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Why assert by *identity*? Are you trying to assert that `pre[i]` is an *instance of* `list`? See [`assertIsInstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance).

Comment: `id(list)` vs `id([1,2,3])`, it's not the same thing

Comment: Yes, I am trying to assert `pre[i]` as an _instance_ of `list`. I am not asserting by identity but, I am having `pre` as a `tuple` of `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIs):

```
assertIs(first, second, msg=None)
assertIsNot(first, second, msg=None)
Test that first and second are (or are not) the same object.
```

Your variable `pre[i]` and built-in datatype `list` is not the same objects (of course if you will not assign `pre[i] = list` or something like that). You should use other method to compare, for example,
[assertIsInstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance).